# RegEx to remove the first line and last line of text in a multiline comment

Tags: regex

what is the regex that can extract a multi line comment, but that has the first line and last line removed, as shown below:
**Input**

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

**Output**

```
Second Line
Third Line
```

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? This sounds like a problem for a different tool. In what context are you working? (Programming language etc)

Comment: Also, if you do need to use a regex, can it be included in the one to find the multi-line comment in the first place, or does it have to be afterwards once you've already extracted the text?

Comment: Sounds like split/join could be your go-to method, depending on what tool as per @txop

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

The solution will depend on format of multiline comments and used language. For multiline comments in C language [this](https://regex101.com/r/MHGs3U/1) could work with flags `gmx`:

```regex
^                # Start of the line followed by
(?:              # any number of the following groups:
  [^'"\/\n]      #   - a normal character, i.e.
                 #     not an apostrophe, a quote, a slash or a new line
|                #
  '\/'           #   - a slash in apostrophes
|                #
  '"'            #   - a quote in apostrophes 
|                #
  "              #   - a quoted string, consisting of the following:
    (?:          #
      [^"\\\/]   #     - not a quote, slash or backslash 
    |            #
      \\.        #     - an escape sequence: a backslash and any character
    |            #
      \/         #     - a slash
    )*+          #   end of quoted string 
  "              #
)*+              # end of pre-comment part of the line
                 #
\/\*.*+\n        # Start of a multi-line comment
(                # Sequence of lines consisting of 
  (?:            #           
    (?:          #
       .         # any character
       (?!\*\/)  # not followed by the end of the comment
    )*+          # repeated any number of times
    \n           # and a new line,
  )+?            #
)                #
.*\*\/           # followed by a line containing an end of comment
```

or in [compressed form](https://regex101.com/r/MHGs3U/2):

```regex
^(?:[^'"\/\n]|'\/'|'"'|"(?:[^"\\\/]|\\.|\/)*+")*+\/\*.*+\n((?:(?:.(?!\*\/))*+\n)+?).*\*\/
```

We use possessive modificators here to avoid unnecessary backtracking, which can significantly reduce performance.

It should be noted, however, that regular expressions are not supposed to be used for parsing of programming languages like C, and some programming languages (like Perl) cannot be statically parsed by any method at all, not just regularly expressions.